# $all with $elemMatch dont work

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongod

Estoy intentando en esta coleccion, obtener coincidencias de solo subdocumentos con el cliente: 2. que solo aparescan dentro del array los subdocumentos que hagan match con cliente:2

```
    introducir el código aquí/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : 3,
    "date" : "14/12/2019",
    "history" : [ 

        {
            "derivative" : null,
            "comments" : "",
            "horaticket" : "21:40:2",
            "horaatencion" : "",
            "horaatendido" : null,
            "_id" : 2,
            "client" : 2,
            "ticket" : {
                "station" : 1,
                "prefix" : "tttt",
                "number" : 2
            },
            "preferencial" : false
        }, 
        {
            "derivative" : null,
            "comments" : "",
            "horaticket" : "21:42:13",
            "horaatencion" : "",
            "horaatendido" : null,
            "_id" : 3,
            "client" : 1,
            "ticket" : {
                "station" : 1,
                "prefix" : "ZZFG",
                "number" : 1
            },
            "preferencial" : false
        }
}
```

Intento esta consulta pero no resulta, solo necesito coincidencias de subdocumentos, creo que la documentación de mongodb no está clara, hay un ejemplo en la documentación pero es confuso

```
db.getCollection('records').find({"history":{ $all:[
                                   {"$elemMatch":{ client:2}}
                                ]} 
            })
```

Comment: Hola @christian-alvarez-sanchez, has probado utilizando esta query: 
`db.getCollection('records').find({"history":{"$elemMatch":{ client:2}}})`.

Answer (score 0):

[$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#element-match) espera un objeto con un operador, en este caso tu quieres todos los que sean iguales a 2, por lo tanto deberías usar [$eq](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/eq/)

Tu query quedaría tal que así:

```
db.getCollection('records').find({"history": {"$elemMatch": {client: {$eq: 2} } })
```

Aquí dejo un link con el ejemplo: https://play.db-ai.co/m/XoIB6YOtowAByn_I